When rotating and shrinking video, which one should I do first?
I'm using FFMPEG to re-encode some videos, while rotating and shrinking them.
Which one should I do first, considering:

Output quality
Output size
Encoding speed

I am aware I can rotate without any reencoding, but that's beside my point.

One solution cannot optimize both "output quality" and the "encoding speed" IMO.

@sawdust: Yeah I realize. Those were independents questions. I'm fine with a different answer for each bullet point.

When encoding a video, ffmpeg will automatically rotate the video if rotate metadata is present in the input. (src) So if you rotate via metadata first and then shrink, you can do both in a single re-encoding. This would be fastest and have the best quality.

@user541686 did my answer help?


Encoding speed

This one is kind of obvious. Rotation doesn't reduce number of pixels while shrinking does. The process of rotating a smaller video will always be relatively faster. Shrinking a rotated video will have more or less the same time as if it wasn't rotated.

Output quality

Rotating a bigger video or image should always result in higher quality of rotation with reencoding. Especially for rotations that aren't standard 90, 180, 270 degree ones. The more pixels there are to work with, the more accurate the end result will be.

Output size

I don't think it matters too much for output size either way. There might be minimal differences that come from quality changes mentioned above, but this shouldn't be your main focus, even when working with big videos. The deviations shouldn't be huge.

You can always quickly test this yourself. This is an example comparison for H.264 MP4 with the following commands:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf transpose=2 output1.mp4
ffmpeg -i output1.mp4 -vf scale=iw/2:ih/2 output1f.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=iw/2:ih/2 output2.mp4
ffmpeg -i output2.mp4 -vf transpose=2 output2f.mp4

In my case, with a ~60 MB file for output1f.mp4 (rotation first) it was:

~29 s for rotation + 9 s for reducing size
~3.5 MB size
very similar quality

And for output2f.mp4 (shrinking first):

~9 s for reducing size + ~7 s for rotation
~3.4 MB size
very similar quality

So the speed was noticably better for shrinking first, the file size just slightly better for that too and the quality wasn't too different for my eyes, although of course a little smaller file size suggests a little bit of quality loss and it would differ more with more complex files and rotations.
